# XSLT to merge XML files based on Condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, mule-studio

Is it possible to merge two xml data files- `Xml-01` and `Xml-02` using the XSLT 1.0. The merge key to use should be based on the values `System` in `Xml-01` mapped with `SystemName` in `Xml-02`.

Final output should be like the one as given below (bottom of post).

I am trying to do this in [Mule Data Mapper](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Datamapper+User+Guide+and+Reference) component of Mule Studio. It doesn't have the necessary features so am trying it with XSLT 1.0.

#### Xml-01

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <ns0:RetrieveMIProcessResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.jupiter.com/RetrieveMI">
      <ns0:Inquiry>
        <ns0:MIId>ID0012</ns0:MIId>
        <ns0:System>System007</ns0:System>
        <ns0:ProductsList>
          <ns0:ProductIDs>
            <ns0:ProductID/>
          </ns0:ProductIDs>
        </ns0:ProductsList>
      </ns0:Inquiry>
      <ns0:Inquiry>
        <ns0:MIId>ID0010</ns0:MIId>
        <ns0:System>System003</ns0:System>
        <ns0:ProductsList>
          <ns0:ProductIDs>
            <ns0:ProductID/>
          </ns0:ProductIDs>
        </ns0:ProductsList>
      </ns0:Inquiry>
      <ns0:Inquiry>
        <ns0:MIId>ID009</ns0:MIId>
        <ns0:System>System006</ns0:System>
        <ns0:ProductsList>
          <ns0:ProductIDs>
            <ns0:ProductID/>
          </ns0:ProductIDs>
        </ns0:ProductsList>
      </ns0:Inquiry>
     </ns0:RetrieveMIProcessResponse>
```

#### Xml-02

```
<ns0:ProductsResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.jupiter.com/RetrieveProducts">
  <ns0:Products>
    <ns0:ProductCode>ProductCode01</ns0:ProductCode>
    <ns0:SystemName>System007</ns0:SystemName>
  </ns0:Products>
  <ns0:Products>
    <ns0:ProductCode>ProductCode02</ns0:ProductCode>
    <ns0:SystemName>System007</ns0:SystemName>
  </ns0:Products>
  <ns0:Products>
    <ns0:ProductCode>ProductCode03</ns0:ProductCode>
    <ns0:SystemName>System003</ns0:SystemName>
  </ns0:Products>
  </ns0:ProductsResponse>
```

#### Final Output -

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:RetrieveMIProcessResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.jupiter.com/RetrieveMI">
  <ns0:Inquiry>
    <ns0:MIId>ID0012</ns0:MIId>
    <ns0:System>System007</ns0:System>
    <ns0:ProductsList>
      <ns0:ProductIDs>
        <ns0:ProductID>ProductCode01</ns0:ProductID>
      </ns0:ProductIDs>
       <ns0:ProductIDs>
        <ns0:ProductID>ProductCode02</ns0:ProductID>
      </ns0:ProductIDs>
    </ns0:ProductsList>
  </ns0:Inquiry>
  <ns0:Inquiry>
    <ns0:MIId>ID0010</ns0:MIId>
    <ns0:System>System003</ns0:System>
    <ns0:ProductsList>
      <ns0:ProductIDs>
        <ns0:ProductID>ProductCode03</ns0:ProductID>
      </ns0:ProductIDs>
    </ns0:ProductsList>
  </ns0:Inquiry>
  <ns0:Inquiry>
    <ns0:MIId>ID009</ns0:MIId>
    <ns0:System>System006</ns0:System>
    <ns0:ProductsList>
      <ns0:ProductIDs>
        <ns0:ProductID/>
      </ns0:ProductIDs>
    </ns0:ProductsList>
  </ns0:Inquiry>
 </ns0:RetrieveMIProcessResponse>

 code here
```

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please say so and show what you have done so far. If not, still show what you have done so far... ;). Welcome to SO, please take a minute to read the [faq].

Comment: Please specify if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: I am new to XSLT am trying to aggregate the payload using Mule Data mapper and that approach is not successful.

Comment: @Vinu, I have updated your question to reflect what I think was your intention, linking also to the product you mentioned. I am wondering though, if you decide **not** to use the tool given and go for another tool (XSLT), why not use a more recent version? XSLT 1.0 is 17 years old, XSLT 2.0 is from 2007 and XSLT 3.0 is upcoming. Consider using [Saxon](http://saxonica.com) or [Exselt](http://exselt.net) (both support most of XSLT 3.0, disclaimer, I co-wrote Exselt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could have been a rather simple lookup, except for:

1. using a key for lookup across documents is awkward in XSLT 1.0;
2. your lookup document is using a different namespace (albeit with the
   same prefix);
3. the need to add empty nodes when the lookup fails (is it really necessary?).

With that in mind, try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.jupiter.com/RetrieveMI"
xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.jupiter.com/RetrieveProducts"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-lookup" select="'02.xml'"/>

<xsl:key name="product-by-system" match="ns1:Products" use="ns1:SystemName" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns0:ProductsList">
    <xsl:variable name="system" select="../ns0:System" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <!-- switch context to lookup document in order to use key -->
        <xsl:for-each select="document($path-to-lookup)">
            <xsl:variable name="matching-products" select="key('product-by-system', $system)" />
            <xsl:for-each select="$matching-products">
                <ns0:ProductIDs>
                    <ns0:ProductID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="ns1:ProductCode"/>
                    </ns0:ProductID>
                </ns0:ProductIDs>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <!-- add empty node when there is no match -->
            <xsl:if test="not($matching-products)">
                <ns0:ProductIDs>
                    <ns0:ProductID/>
                </ns0:ProductIDs>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The general idea here is that Xml-01 would be the main input document for your XSLT, and you would load the secondary Xml-02 using the [`document()` function](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp).

Comment: You cannot load a document with `xsl:document`, that is used to create a document node. Perhaps you mean `fn:doc` or `fn:document`?

Comment: You are correct, my bad -- I meant the document() function.  I will fix my answer.